# Getting Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented

Tags: postgresql, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5

I created a new Play 2.5.3 project and I'm getting this error.

I read in another answer the driver was out of date, so I added what I believe to be the latest driver like this:

I added the postgress driver dependency like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)
```

But still getting the error.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The most recent version is `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1208"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this function is really not implemented in version 9.1-901 of the driver
see a source code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java#AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid%28int%29

```
117    public boolean isValid(int timeout) throws SQLException
118    {
119        checkClosed();
120        throw org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(this.getClass(), "isValid(int)");
121    }
```

---

You can use a newer version of the driver, currently the newest driver is: Version 9.4-1208, see this link: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/

---

Or you can implement this funcion on your own - you can copy their implementation from here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41/org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java#AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid%28int%29

```
127    public boolean isValid(int timeout) throws SQLException
128    {
129        if (isClosed()) {
130            return false;
131        }
132     if (timeout < 0) {
133            throw new PSQLException(GT.tr("Invalid timeout ({0}<0).", timeout), PSQLState.INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE);
134        }
135     boolean valid = false;
136        Statement stmt = null;
137     try {
138         if (!isClosed()) {
139             stmt = createStatement();
140             stmt.setQueryTimeout( timeout );
141             stmt.executeUpdate( "" );
142             valid = true;
143         }
144     }
145     catch ( SQLException e) {
146         getLogger().log(GT.tr("Validating connection."),e);
147     }
148     finally
149     {
150         if(stmt!=null) try {stmt.close();}catch(Exception ex){}
151     }
152        return valid;    
153}
```